# Newbie looking to collect Movie Like data

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, movies

I'm looking to collect Facebook Movie Like information.

I don't need anything other the the Movie Likes, grouped by an ID.

e.g.:

```
ID, like 1,       like 2,       like 3 etc...
1,  Bad boys,     bad boys 2,   Santa Clause the movie
2,  Bad santa,    god father, 
3,  team america, inception,    the matrix
4,  bad boys,     team america, inception
```

I'm familiar with PHP/MySQL, so would prefer to use that.  However, I really want the data so will try/learn anything.

From using the search, I found this from 3 years ago:

```
SELECT name, page_id
FROM page
WHERE page_id IN
(
    SELECT page_id
    FROM page_fan
    WHERE uid IN
    (
        SELECT uid2
        FROM friend
        WHERE uid1 = me()
    )
    AND profile_section='movies'
 )
```

Comment: You won't be able to run SQL statements on Facebook unless they give you access (highly-unlikely). You should start by researching an API from which you can pull this information if they provide one.

Comment: Do I need the user to grant me access to get this information, or is it public?

Comment: I can access peoples Movie likes without being their friend, does this mean if they allow public browsing, I can get the data via the API?

Comment: The total likes is probably public, but individual likes probably depends on a users privacy settings. I don't know if there is an API from which to pull this information.

Comment: Is there anyway to get individual likes without screen scrapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the Movie likes info of individual by requesting the permission `user_likes` for the individual app user.

I don't really understand your structure (`...grouped by an ID`). How should this work anyway?